# Physical significance of Cayley Transform

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, linear-algebra

In the book on Quantum Mechanics by Capri (in Chapter 6), its said that an operator $A$ is self adjoint if the operator, $U$ given by

$$ U = (A - i I)(A + i I)^{-1} = -(I+iA)(I-iA)^{-1} = -\text e^{iA} ({\text e^{-iA}})^{-1}  $$

Now if I define, some $B \equiv \frac{\alpha}{2} A$, then

$$ U(\alpha) = \text e^{i\alpha B}$$

Now, this self-adjoint operator can be associated to the Unitary operator and its single parameter formed by it.

**Question : Can I relate the Cayley transform itself to some physical idea behind it, and hence a physical idea behind Self-adjointness of an operator ?**

Comment: the last equality of the first formulas seems a little bit suspect...this may hold for special operators, but I doubt it holds in general (the $I\pm iA$ is just a truncation of the exponential, even formally).

Comment: I hope it holds for any self-adjoint related to a continuous transformation.

Comment: I am saying that $-(I+iA)(I-ia)^{-1}=-e^{iA}(e^{-ia})^{-1}$ does not hold in general. Anyways, to any self-adjoint operator $A$ is associated a one-parameter strongly continuous unitary group of transformations $e^{isA}$, $s\in\mathbb{R}$; also vice versa to any strongly continuous unitary group of transformations $U(s)$, $s\in\mathbb{R}$, is associated a self-adjoint operator $A=\lim_{h\to 0} h^{-1}(U(h)-I)$. I.e. there is a one-to-one correspondence between strongly continuous unitary groups and self-adjoint operators. This is the Stone's theorem.

Comment: The physical idea is that to any self-adjoint hamiltonian we can associate a unique global solution of the Schrödinger equation, i.e. the quantum evoution of the system. In fact, given $\psi(0)=\psi_0$, and the equation $i\partial_t \psi = H\psi$, with $H$ auto-adjoint, then the unique solution of the equation is $\psi(t)=e^{-itH}\psi_0$.